# Check if date is between two dates in c (Arrays)

Tags: c, arrays

I have three int arrays

```
int a[3] = {2,25,2015} //Date : d,mm,yyyy
int b[3] = {4,15,2016}
int c[3] = {7,10,2017}
```

I want to check if b is between a and c

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: At least write a line of code which fails, then we will start to modify it.
your question looks like: "Do My Homwork"

Comment: Please add the Stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following little program does exactly what you want. Note: you can easily use the `smaller` function to create all boolean operators (`<=, >=, ==, !=, >`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int Date[3];

int smaller(Date a, Date b)
{
  if (a[2] < b[2]) return 1; // compare years
  if (a[2] == b[2] && a[1] < b[1]) return 1; // compare months - but make sure years are equal
  if (a[2] == b[2] && a[1] == b[1] && a[0] < b[0]) return 1; // compare days but make sure years and months are equal
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  Date a = {2,25,2015}; //Date : d,mm,yyyy
  Date b = {4,15,2016};
  Date c = {7,10,2017};

  printf("%s\n", (smaller(a, b) && smaller(b, c)) ? "b between a and c" : "b is not between a and c");
}
```

The `typedef` is to make the code more easy to read. You can still also

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of problem that is better approached with a different mindset than what we are used. Comparing dates is easier if we convert it to another form (i.e. ellapsed days or ellapsed seconds since some point of reference).

In your case, I see two options:

1. Create a small function that converts from standard date format (dd/mm/yyyy) to a ellapsed days format since a reference time (i.e. converting 25/02/2016 to ellapsed day since 01/01/2016 would give us 31 + 25 = 56 days);
2. Use C's very own [time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/). It gives you the ellapsed seconds since 01/01/1970 (a.k.a. 'epoch').

Answer (score 0):

You must compare each value of array b with each correspondent value of arrays a and c. You can try the following:

```
if ( (b[2] <= c[2]) && (b[2] >= a[2]) )          //comparing years
   if ( (b[1] <= c[1]) && (b[1] >= a[1]) )      //comparing months
       if ( (b[0] <= c[0]) && (b[0] >= a[0]) )   //comparing days
              // ... b is between a and c, so do something ....
```

However, it would be better if you showed the code you have tried so that we could help you modify it.

Comment: year should be compared first

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming between means not inclusive..

bool isDateWithinRange = false;
for(i=2;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(a[i]<b[i] && b[i]<c[i]){
        isDateWithinRange = true;
        break;
    }
    if(a[i]>b[i] || b[i]>c[i])
        break;
}
```

Comment: This will create an error since the first position it checks is `a[3]` wich is not part of the array.